# Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase/index'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, import

I am trying to import firebase in my react app, using the following syntax:

`import firebase from 'firebase/index';`

But I am facing following issue:

`./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase/index' in '/home/neosoft/Documents/react_projects/urup_dashboard/src'`

I am not sure what is the issue, as I am a newbie to react.

**UPDATE**
I have noticed a strange thing. The above syntax of import works fine in ubuntu 14.04. The issue is faced in ubuntu 16.04. I am not sure about other versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 27):

You need to run `npm install firebase` from your project folder

Answer (score 7):

Try upgrading firebase back to `"firebase": "4.8.0"`

Follow steps below

```
1. Do npm uninstall firebase
2. npm cache clear
3. npm i firebase@^4.8.0 --save
```

Comment: My current version of firebase is 5.5.3 and firebase-tools is 5.0.0.

Answer (score 7):

uninstall the firebase version that you have in package.json with `npm uninstall firebase` and install this version instead `npm i firebase@^8.10.0`

Answer (score 4):

According to the Firebase documentation at npm, you have to import the entire Firebase namespace as:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

In order to use specific services inside firebase, you must import them without a name:

```js
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Note: While developing your Firebase application, you will likely get a message that you are using the development build of Firebase. In production builds, you should import firebase from `firebase/app`:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Answer (score 3):

if you need to clear the cache after unistalling the current version of firebase

```
npm uninstall firebase
```

doing

```
npm clear cache
```

your computer might not want to do it
and sends

```
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.
```

then listen and use

```
npm clear cache --force
```

and then it's ok you can do

```
npm i firebase@^4.8.0 --save
```

and you're good !

Comment: Simply updating the firebase version to 4.8.0 in package.json and re-running the `npm install` command works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sue about this version? 
```zsh: no matches found: firebase@^4.8.0```

Answer (score 1):

on the terminal do the followng:

```
yarn remove firebase
yarn add firebase
```

After this on firebase.js file do the following

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is firebase folder in node_modules
if there is no firebase folder then

```
npm i firebase
```

if there is firebase folder then

```
npm uninstall firebase
```

then

```
npm i firebase
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when I used vanilla ReactJS (no typescript) and firebase version 9.1.1

I resolved it like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "@firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "@firebase/auth";
```

In my other typescript project, I do not require `@` sign in front of the library name in import statement and that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are  facing  this  issue
try these   lines
use  this drill down approach ....
make  sure  you  have  firebase  installl if  not   use  these  lines

> npm installl firebase

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/storage";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
```

it  should   work  ,thanks

Answer (score -1):

go to this link
https://github.com/jeescu/react-firebase

do in terminal

> git clone
>
> cd react-firebase
>
> npm install

Open the installed directory i.e react-firebase in explorer.
Open "node_modules" folder copy firebase folder and paste it in your project "node_modules" folder :
NB: not a permanent solution though